# Modal with javascript works in a class, but doesn't in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to fix some bugs in the application. It has a class `User` and in the controller I have method `display` defined like this:

```
def display
  respond_to :js    
end
```

In views user's, I have a .js, called display.js.

And finally, in the `users_helper', I have a method:

```
def display_user_link(user, truncate_username = false)
  unless user.nil?
    username = truncate_username ? smart_truncate(user.username, length: 12) : user.username
    link_to_if(true, username,  display_user_path(user),
               class: 'icon-user-display', remote: true)
  end
end
```

In views, I can call this method like:

```
<%= display_user_link(user, true) %>
```

It shows a link and when I click it a modal appears.

I've created another class, called UserReports, and I'm tryng to do the same thing, but it's not working.

I've checked the logs and noticed that the log for clicking link for User is the same as when I click the link for UserReports.

Comment: Few pointers: There are not called `defs` but methods. `def` is a key word reserved for defining `methods`. Also there is not enough information to help you here. You mentioned modals - are you using Twitter bootstrap? You said you tried the same for UserReports and it is not working - we will need to see the code which is not working rather than working version for another model. And lastly, what is `link_to_if`?

Comment: Thanks for orientations, I found the problem. I'm using datatables to sort my table in client-side. So, in a view UserReport's, I add a <script></script> and the two .js files. Testing, I commented the script and the javascript_include, so, I think the problem is the way I'm including the files, I should to use assets to compile, instead add the script in view. I will to try do this. =]